# How to save only lines containing a particular String (in a CSV file) as a separate CSV file?

Tags: android, python, file, parsing, csv

I want to save only lines containing a particular String (in a CSV file) as a separate CSV file?

Consider the following file:

```
foo,bar,zig,zag
zog,bar,zag,zag
qux,zig,zag,zag
quuux,bar,zag,zag
```

When filtered for bar, the result should be a separate CSV file:

```
foo,bar,zig,zag
zog,bar,zag,zag
quuux,bar,zag,zag
```

What's the most efficient way to achieve this? Is there code to do this, as I need to do it for about 200 such names as "bar".

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What is the problem? Reading text files? Parsing comma-separated lines? Filtering lists? Creating comma-separated strings? Writing text files?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. If you have no clue, have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just filter each row by a certain column (assuming it's always the same column):

```
import csv

names = ['bar', 'foo', 'foobar']
data = []

# read data
with open('all.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in spamreader:
        if row[1] in names:
            data.append(row)

# maybe some more processing
# ...

# write back data that meets criteria
with open('bar.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    spamwriter.writerows(data)
```

Comment: This works, but can you please explain what to do if I want to search for a part of the column and not the full column. For ex... I have columns with "Europe/France" and "Europe/Germany"...  and I want to save all lines with just Europe in them...

Comment: You could for example add `Europe` to the names list, split up the row by `/` and take the first part, so the condition would look like `if row[1].split('/')[0] in names:`

Comment: I have one more question (I will create a new question if needed) - it is that what if I want to sort one column alphabetically? Is that possible? what is the best way to do this? as I need it sorted on the 2nd column, so sorted() function doesn't work. Update: Pl. ignore. I swapped the columns and sorted it. Any other ways?